# Fallback to normal function if celery is not active

Tags: python, django, celery

What I require is a simple hack for running function synchronously if celery is not active.

What I tried is:
`is_celery_working` returns False although celery and Redis both are running (ran `celery -A project worker -l debug` and `redis-server` respectively). Also `get_celery_worker_status` is always giving `error` in status.

I am using celery with Django.

```py
from project.celery import app

def is_celery_working():
    result = app.control.broadcast('ping', reply=True, limit=1)
    return bool(result)  # True if at least one result


def sync_async(func):
    if is_celery_working():
        return func.delay
    else:
        return func

sync_async(some_func)(**its_args, **its_kwrgs)
```

```py
def get_celery_worker_status():
    error_key = 'error'

    try:
        from celery.task.control import inspect
        insp = inspect()
        d = insp.stats()
        if not d:
            d = {error_key: 'No running Celery workers were found.'}
    except IOError as e:
        from errno import errorcode
        msg = "Error connecting to the backend: " + str(e)
        if len(e.args) > 0 and errorcode.get(e.args[0]) == 'ECONNREFUSED':
            msg += ' Check that the RabbitMQ server is running.'
        d = {error_key: msg}
    except ImportError as e:
        d = {error_key: str(e)}
    return d

def sync_async(func):
    status = get_celery_worker_status()
    if 'error' not in status:
        return func.delay
    else:
        return func

sync_async(some_func)(**its_args, **its_kwrgs)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
def sync_async(func, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
        func.delay(*args, **kwargs)
    except Exception as error:
        print('Celery not active', error)
        func(*args, **kwargs)
```

This just gives an error if the Redis server is not working. This worked fine for me as I am assuming that if Redis is not working then celery is stopped.

Answer (score 0):

Your simple `is_celery_working` function looks correct.  If you're getting `False`, you may want to increase your timeout to `5` or `10` seconds using the optional `timeout` parameter.

```py
def is_celery_working():
    result = app.control.broadcast('ping', reply=True, limit=1, timeout=5.0)
    return bool(result)  # True if at least one result
```

Comment: But I want to time this to be quick, waiting for 5sec is too long.

Comment: I guess you're in a conundrum then--because your code works great as is.  This means you are seeing false negatives with a one second timeout.  So, you can either deal with false negatives, or increase the timeout decrease their likelihood.  If neither option is acceptable, you're stuck.

Comment: I tried used Redis connection error to detect no connection with celery. Any task will raise connection error if Redis is not working. This approach worked for my use case.